# define variable with defparameter with name determined at runtime

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I would like to initiate dynamically a hash table with `defmethod` or `defun` using one of the arguments to create the name.  For instance:

```
(defun foo (arg)
  (let ((NAME (read-from-string (format nil "\*~S\*" arg))))
    (defparameter NAME (make-hash-table))))
```

Of course, `foo` create hash table with the symbol `NAME`, instead of the value of `NAME` in `let`. What can I do to get the value of `NAME` to create this hash table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### General Remarks

- It is almost always wrong to create global variables in functions.
- It is also almost always wrong to create new symbols using [`read-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm) instead of [`intern`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm).

### Use a Macro

What you probably want is

```
(defmacro def-ht (name)
  (let ((var (intern (concatenate 'string "*" (symbol-name name) "*")
                     (symbol-package name))))
    `(defparameter ,var (make-hash-table))))
(def-ht foo)
```

### Use a Function

You might be able to do it in a function too - by inspecting the [macroexpansion](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm) of a [`defparameter`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) form and placing the needed stuff in the function:

```
(defun make-ht-var (name)
  (let ((var (intern (concatenate 'string "*" (symbol-name name) "*")
                     (symbol-package name))))
    (setf (symbol-value var) (make-hash-table))
    (proclaim (list var 'special))))
(make-ht-var 'foo)
```

Note that the argument to the function *is* quoted, but the argument to the macro is *not*.

Comment: The defmacro defht does the job on its own. But, now I want to use this function inside a defmethod: `(defmethod init :after ((self myclass)) (deft self))` and in this case, I get a hash table called \*self\* instead of the self name.

Comment: of course - that's because the macro does not evaluate its arguments. you need to use the function version.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a macro instead of a function. DEFPARAMETER will bind value of MAKE-HASH-TABLE to the symbol NAME because it evaluates at macro-expansion time which occurs earlier than run-time, which is when the function FOO binds the lexical value of NAME.

Look up the CL evaluation model for a deeper understanding.

```
(defmacro foo (arg)
  (let ((name (read-from-string (format nil "*~S*" arg))))
    `(defparameter ,name (make-hash-table)))) 

(foo "my-hash")
 => <hash-table 0x121>

*my-hash*
=> <hash-table 0x121>
```

Comment: This probably isn't what OP wants, because if OP does, e.g., `(defun bar (x) (foo x))`, OP will get a hash table named `*x*`, even when doing, e.g,. `(bar "my-hash")`.

Comment: Got it. `(defmethod init ((self myclass)) (eval (list 'defparameter (read-from-string (format nil "*~S*" self)) '(make-hash-table))))` ... thanks

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, you're totally right. My version only works at the top level.